# Windows Azure turned £ (GB Pound symbol) to $ (US Dollar symbol)

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

In my code I have this:

```
@String.Format("{0:c}", item.Amount)
```

It shows for example £4.50 when I run it in debugging mode. When I deployed my app to Windows Azure however it outputs $4.50.

I have deployed to a West Europe website, but obviously the config is set to USA locale. Does anyone know if there's a way for me to manually tell my Azure Website to use £ symbols instead?

I am drifting toward the app settings section under config, but I don't know what key/value to put here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Solution would be something like:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

within your `system.web` section of web.config.

Good to know is that all VMs in Windows Azure run with default USA locale and UTC time.

Comment: Brilliant! I can be so daft at times. I actually found that article and saw that line, but was looking around the Windows Azure config section for where to put it rather than do the obvious and drop it in to web.config and re-deploy. D'uh! Thanks for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't edit the `web.config` file, or you just want to set it in code, you can add to the `program.cs` file (.NET 6):

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
```

and immediately after Routing Middleware is added to the processing pipeline:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("en-GB");
```

As seen in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#statically-set-the-culture)